# Configure default chain in config.toml in meta-toolkit

Tags: c++, search-engine, text-mining, meta-toolkit

I want to configure a config.toml file in [meta-toolkit](https://meta-toolkit.github.io/meta/) with default filter chain but specifying each of the filters. I plan to make modifications to some of the filters so I want to have a baseline filter chain.

I have tried the following attributes:

```
[[analyzers]]
method = "ngram-word"
ngram = 1
    [[analyzers.filter]]
    type = "icu-tokenizer"

    [[analyzers.filter]]
    type = "lowercase"

    [[analyzers.filter]]
    type = "alpha"

    [[analyzers.filter]]
    type = "length"  
    min = 2
    max = 35

    [[analyzers.filter]]
    type = "list"
    filename = "../data/lemur-stopwords.txt"

    [[analyzers.filter]]
    type = "porter2-stemmer"

    [[analyzers.filter]]
    type = "empty-sentence"
```

I'm getting:

> token_stream_exception: what(): file required for list_filter config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute should be file instead of filename.

```
[[analyzers.filter]]
type = "list"
file = "../data/lemur-stopwords.txt"
```